# Ubuntu 14.04 -Android Studio: The following classes could not be instantiated

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04, instantiation

I've started to delve into app development and I'm following some online tutorials and I've come across this rendering issue. Whenever I select any theme other than AppTheme.NoActionBar I get an error along the following lines.

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom
>   views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE 
>   Exception Details
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with the design library.   at
>   android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:178)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:172)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) Copy
>   stack to clipboard

Look over all the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)  from changing appTheme in Styles and changing things in the AndroidManifest but nothing seems to work. I'm still receiving rendering problems in my content main.

My Styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is my default XMLs, but even the changes suggest had no avail. Its been around 2 months and I still haven't gotten past this...

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331836/java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-des, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063395/actionbarcompat-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcom

Comment: I have looked at all those answers and I can't find out what I need to do.

Comment: you can try by recreating caches & indexes. Go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.... Maybe this help!

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. You can set this in your `styles.xml` found in your resources, `res/values/styles.xml`.

Comment: Still running into the issue.