# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-theme

I am trying to implement "Flexible Space with Image" from Material Design with the help of this tutorial:

[Toolbar animation with android design support library](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/)

But I am getting this Rendering problem message in the layout preview :

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>
> - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

I applied the `Theme.AppCompat` theme to my application but it screws up the action bar and appearance in every other activity. 
Also it throws an error on action bar methods such as :

> actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

stating the error(roughly) as :

> setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean) is being called on a null object reference

Additionally using `Theme.AppCompat` for the entire application gives the following error in the preview screen :

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Fix Build Path, Create Class)

Thus I don't want to use `Theme.AppCompat` for the entire application. However, using a `Theme.AppCompat` for the specific activity where I want to use the "Flexible space with image" design doesn't resolve the `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout` issue stated earlier.

Please tell me what to do! I have read many stackoverflow posts on the same issue but they didn't work for me! I have restarted android studio and invalidated my cache and restarted countless times as well!!

Here are the dependencies in my `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':viewPagerIndicator')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Running the app as is on my phone gives me this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action
>   bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Setting the windowActionBar to false like so :

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

and then running the app throws this error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.seven.actionbar/com.seven.actionbar.EventsDetailActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the
>   current theme features: { windowActionBar: false,
>   windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false,
>   windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }

Here is the toolbar bit from the EventsDetailsActivity.java file :

```
    Toolbar toolbar;
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_eventsdetail);

        actionBarColor =
                new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.ufl_orange));

        tDes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.evt_desc);
        tVenue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.evt_venue);
        tDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.evt_date);
        tTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.evt_time);
        tPdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.evt_post_date);
        tPtime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.evt_post_time);
        tCont = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.evt_contact);
        tOrg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.evt_org);
        tCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.evt_count);

        //Intent intent = getIntent();
        //joinMap = (HashMap)intent.getSerializableExtra("e_uMap");
        myApp = (MyApp)getApplication();

        //action bar magic
        actionBarColor.setAlpha(0);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.anim_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);

        new LoadDetail().execute();

        goingSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.btn_join);
        goingSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                new JoinEvents().execute(String.valueOf(isChecked));
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
//        actionBar = this.getActionBar();
//        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    }
```

Here is the layout code that goes with it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".EventsDetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/monalisa"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>'

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `ScrollView` and associated child elements(not shown here) is the main content of the page.

Also modified the theme to:

```
<style name="EventsTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

While the `IllegalStateException` and `RuntimeException` are gone I can't see the `CoordinatorLayout` again.

false

Comment: Did you add your support-design library as a library project

Comment: Yea I did. I've updated my question.

Comment: Try changing the layout preview to a lower Api about Api-19

Comment: Changing the preview is not the really the issue. When I upload the app on my phone I can't see the `CoordinatorLayout` part in the activity.

Comment: Updated the question with details about running the app as is.

Comment: why do you have two different versions of the support library in your gradle dependency? remove 23.0.1 you don't need two versions alos share some code other than your 1 line style

Comment: Done. Removed the earlier version of the library.

Comment: set `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` theme & remove duplicate `support:appcompat` from `build.gradle` .Then clean ,Rebuild & sync and run

Answer (score 4):

### Whats your logcat Throws

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action
>   bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

1. All of your themes (that want an **Action Bar/Toolbar**) must inherit
   from **Theme.AppCompat**. There are variants available, **including Light
   and NoActionBar.**

Please Read Official Document about [AppCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

### What should you do

1. Please set **`parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`** instead of
   **parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light**"
2. Avoid **Duplicate Library** Calling . `support:appcompat` called two times in your **`build.gradle`** section .

You can check similar types of question on ***SO***

1. [Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923403/do-not-request-window-feature-action-bar-issue)
2. [AppCompat does not support the current theme features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063395/actionbarcompat-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcom

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331836/java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-des

Comment: Yea I've already mentioned your steps in the comments. And they're not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

OK! the famous Toolbar problem.

As from what it seems, try making few changes in the code you have posted.

**1)** If you want ActionBar in other activities but this one, create a new style for NoActionBar and add that style to this Activity

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Noe in you `AndroidManifest.xml`, assign this theme so that only `EventsDetailsActivity` will **not** have ActionBar but rest will.

```
<activity
        android:name="EventsDetailsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

**2)** The `ScrollView` does not work well with the `CoordinatorLayout`. So in order to achieve [‘Flexible Space with Image‘](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-scrolling) try `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`. This will give you proper animation effect.

**3)** Change the `ActionBar` with a `Toolbar` in your `EventsDetailsActivity`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to use `Toolbar`? Do you need to support some old Android versions?
The point is that a `Toolbar` is not actually `ActionBar`. It lacks some functionality and forces you to use definite Themes on your Activities. So if you don't need to support some old versions of Android [(v7.Toolbar is for SDK 7 (Android 2.1).](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/features.html)

Oh, and by the way: what are you trying to do is called collapsing toolbar layout. Check this link for tutorial 
http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

P.S. Do not compile different versions of the same library! Don't do this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':viewPagerIndicator')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Instead, change it to this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':viewPagerIndicator')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Comment: "Why do you need to use Toolbar? Do you need to support some old Android versions?" Toolbar is Added in API level 21. So please reply, what do you think we should use instead of Toolbar ; if we don't have to support older versions that 21

Comment: At discussion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813474/should-we-replace-action-bar-by-toolbar, it is advised to use Toolbar instead of ActionBar

Comment: I gave the answer 1,5 years ago, and I reconsidered my position as AppBarLayout appeared. So I am using Toolbar myself these days. Though, a gut asked what to do if you don't want to set AppCompat theme for your activity.

Comment: yes, Google changed it a lot...it's water under the bridge now